# <hr>:after places element before

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to place a small dot at the end of my `<hr>` tag using `::after`. But instead the element gets added as if it where added ::before. To style the `<hr>` I'm using Tailwind, but doing the ::after styling with CSS. Here's an image of what it looks like now, the dot is to the left. I would like it to just place the small dot at the other end of the line, to the right.

[image]

This is my code:

CSS

```
.right::after {
    content: ' ';
    width: 5px;
    height: 6px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -6px;
    margin-left: -1px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 5px solid #9596ff;
    background-color: #9596ff;
}
```

HTML

```
    <hr class="right mt-7 mb-5 border-t-1 w-full">
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the class `right` make it float right, by any chance? I think we'd need to know what properties all those classes give the element (and therefore it'll probably be easier to make an example with fewer classes)

Comment: Hi! No, they don't, I only use .right to select it in my CSS. The other classes are just margin top & bottom, a border property and full width. But I could remove them from my example if it just adds confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify `position: relative` of `hr`, otherwise the dot would be positioned according to the rest of the page.

```css
.right {
    display: block;
    position: relative; 
}
.right::after {
    content: ' ';
    width: 5px;
    height: 6px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -6px;
    margin-left: -1px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 5px solid #9596ff;
    background-color: #9596ff;
    top: -1px;
    right: -1px;
}
```

```html
<hr class="right mt-7 mb-5 border-t-1 w-full">
```

Comment: Thank you! This is it! It also works perfectly on smaller screens as well. Can't believe I forgot the relative position. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `position: absolute;` you will need to add `right: 0;` to move it over. CSS would look like this.

```
.right::after {
    content: ' ';
    width: 5px;
    height: 6px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -6px;
    margin-left: -1px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 5px solid #9596ff;
    background-color: #9596ff;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to make that more responsive? I have to add right:10px or something similar, because right:0 places it in the far end of the screen, the line isn't that wide.

Answer (score 0):

You have position absolute but provide no placement instructions.

I added

```
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
```

to `.right::after`:

```css
.right::after {
  content: ' ';
  width: 5px;
  height: 6px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 5px solid #9596ff;
  background-color: #9596ff;
}
```

```html
<hr class="right mt-7 mb-5 border-t-1 w-full">
```

And to make the dot look more like your image:

```css
.right::after {
  content: ' ';
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 6px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #9596ff;
}
```

```html
<hr class="right mt-7 mb-5 border-t-1 w-full">
```